# TextView in TableView cell not moving up when keyboard hide it in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use below code to move TextView up when keyboard hide it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()             

        registerForKeyboardNotifiactions()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }

 var textsView = UITextView()

    func registerForKeyboardNotifiactions(){
        let ncUp = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:     "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        var ncDown = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:   "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let info = aNotification.userInfo!

        let kbSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().size
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0)

        tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect = self.view.frame        
        aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height

        if !CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, textsField.frame.origin) {
            self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(textsField.frame , animated: true)
        }

        else if !CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, textsView.frame.origin) {
            self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(textsView.frame , animated: true)
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(aNotifiacation: NSNotification){
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }   

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->    UITableViewCell {

        let cells = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentCell", forIndexPath:    indexPath) as! MakeCommentCell

        self.textsView = cells.textView 
    cells.textView.delegate = self     
        textsField = cells.textField return cells 
    }
```

It work fine with TextField but in case of TextView its not working. I tried lots of things as to change bottom constraints and other suggestion that I could find in Stack OverFlow and other site but none seems to work for me (I might not have understood it clearly).

How could I make it work?

If there is better way I would love to know it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some thing wrong with the part of your code that checks whether the textField/textViews frame is covered by the keyboard.

Before you compare CGGeometry structs you should make sure they are from the same coordinate space. 
The frame property of the textView is on the coordinate space of it's superview, w/c I understand is the contentView of a table cell. You should probably not compare it directly with view.frame w/c is on the coordinate space of view.superview.

UIView and UICoordinateSpace has methods to convert these structs.

Anyway, here's how I would do the check:

```
let keyboardFrame = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()//the keyboard end frame on the coordinate space of the app's window
let textViewFrame = textView.convertRect(textView.bounds, toView: nil)//the textView frame on the coordinate space of the app's window
if CGRectIntersectsRect(keyboardFrame, textViewFrame) {
    let textViewFrame = textView.convertRect(textView.bounds, toView:self.tableView) //textView frame on the coord space of tableView
    self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(textViewFrame , animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I don't think that 's the issue. My code is working properly with textfield